# How to calculate probability of bankruptcy for $E>0$ and given $\sigma$?

Tags: standard-deviation, expected-value

I will demonstrate the problem with the simple example. Suppose I want to start a casino. The probability theory tells me that the expected value for my games is greater than zero ($E>0$), and therefore I can expect to profit in the long run.

But in the same time, I am aware of the negative streak risk. It just might happen that the gambler will win enough times in a row that I will at one point have to declare a bankruptcy. Therefore, I want to know what budget do I need to have in order to avoid the bankruptcy (in theory, this is unavoidable, but one can accept probability small enough).

To be even more concrete, let's say that I want to calculate the **safe budget** in the roulette black / red game. Now I know that the expected value for \$1 stake is $E=\$ 0.053$. That means that, on average, I will profit ¢5 on each roll. I also know that standard deviation for this game is roughly $\sigma= \$1$ (this is easy to calculate by the definition). Let's also assume that I have a budget of \$1000. What is the probability of me going bankrupt? What budget do I need to have in order to have p(bankruptcy) < 0.01?

Any ideas on how to approach this?

Comment: google for "gamble ruins problem", you will get a lot of hits ...

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know this is the term. I found this on wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risk_of_ruin - there is even the formula for p(ruin), which includes E, sigma and bankroll. I think this could be the result I am looking for.